# PrettyPhoto Jquery Plugin, use span instead of anchor and achieve same results

Tags: jquery, lightbox, prettyphoto

I am using PrettyPhoto Jquery plugin as a Lightbox for displaying images on my site, when the user clicked the thumbnail, the image appear in an overlay DIV.

By default, PrettyPhoto works with anchor links (`<a>`) that surrounds the image. The anchor has the links to the original size / larger version of the image. I don't want to use `<a>` tag because I prefer that those images won't be indexed and don't wont to use nofollow. Is there an option to replace the `<a>` with  for example and achieve the same results?

I tried it myself but it didn't trigger the overlay div with the original image as intended. Maybe there is something that I can do in the code to make it work.

Again, Don't want:

```
 <a href="original-image.jpg"><img src="thumb,jpg /></a>
```

Do want:

```
 <span data-source="original-image.jpg"><img src="thumb.jpg /></span>
```

The original file non-compressed Jquery plugin can be downloaded [via this link](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/demos/prettyPhoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/prettyPhoto_uncompressed_3.1.4.zip)

Another alternative that might be good is to keep the anchoe but use `href="#"` and put the original image URL in another attribute, like 'data-source' and read it from there. This is even a better option.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this line in the plug-in

```
pp_images = (isSet) ? jQuery.map(matchedObjects, function(n, i){ if($(n).attr(settings.hook).indexOf(theRel) != -1) return $(n).attr('href'); }) : $.makeArray($(this).attr('href'));
```

to

```
pp_images = (isSet) ? jQuery.map(matchedObjects, function(n, i){ if($(n).attr(settings.hook).indexOf(theRel) != -1) return $(n).attr('data-source'); }) : $.makeArray($(this).attr('data-source'));
```

EDIT: and

```
set_position = jQuery.inArray($(this).attr('href'), pp_images); // Define where in the array the clicked item is positionned
```

to

```
set_position = jQuery.inArray($(this).attr('data-source'), pp_images); // Define where in the array the clicked item is positionned
```

Comment: It triggers the lightbox, but it shows the ajax loader without the image

Comment: you were 90% correct, just also need to change it also here: set_position = jQuery.inArray($(this).attr('data-source'), pp_images); (LINE 160) - update the answer.

Comment: @devnull69 I was trying to use the prettyphoto. Do you know how to block scroll on the body, when lightbox is up? and also change the size of light box (ie, not restricted to the screen size?) I am trying to get pinterest style functionality.